# OCMock and Blocks

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, ocmock

I have a method with the following signature that I want to test using OCMock's stub feature:

```
- (void)signInWithEmail:(NSString *)email andWithPassword:(NSString *)password andWithBlock:(void (^)(GNCustomer *customer, NSError *error))block
```

How would I go about mocking this to handle the returned block.

I have tried:

```
[[_mockAuthenticationRepository stub] signInWithEmail:[OCMArg any] andWithPassword:[OCMArg any] andWithBlock:^(GNCustomer *customer, NSError *error) {

            }];
```

When I try to stub with this approach, I received unexpected method invoked which indicates that my stub is not being used.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I figured this out :)  Here's the answer:

```
[[[_mockAuthenticationRepository stub] andDo:^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
                void (^successBlock)(GNCustomer *customer, NSError *error) = nil;

                [invocation getArgument:&successBlock atIndex:4];

                NSDictionary *details = @{ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : [OCMArg any] };
                NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Some Domain" code:401 userInfo:details];

                successBlock(nil, error);
            }] signInWithEmail:[OCMArg any] andWithPassword:[OCMArg any] andWithBlock:[OCMArg any]];
```

Comment: The atIndex option also refers to the point in the method signature the block is called starting with an index of 2 for the first param.