# OCMock stub blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock, promisekit

I try to stub this AFNetworking method and test error case:

```
- (void)setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                          failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure;
```

My test method look like:

```
it(@"should return error when remote api fails", ^{
    id mock = OCMClassMock([AFHTTPRequestOperation class]);
    OCMStub([mock setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:[OCMArg any] failure:[OCMArg any]]).andDo(^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
      void (^failureBlock)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) = nil;
      [invocation getArgument:&failureBlock atIndex:3];
      NSDictionary *details = @{ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : [OCMArg any] };
      NSError *err = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Some Domain" code:401 userInfo:details];
      failureBlock(nil, err);         
    });
    [API getWeeklyEvents].catch(^(NSError *err) {
      error = [err copy];
    });
    expect(error).will.beTruthy();
});
```

Also `[API getWeeklyEvents]`method uses PromiseKit. Can it be an issue?

I tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388051/ocmock-and-blocks) but it doesnt work and uses old OCMock syntax.

Answer (score 1):

So, you've stubbed the `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:` method with a block that actually calls the failure handler. This means, as far as OCMock is concerned, that nothing will happen until someone else calls `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure`.

Now that method is an instance method and would have to be invoked on the mock. The only method that is called is `getWeekEvents`. I'm not sure how that would be able to call that set method because it would need a reference to the mock.

To be honest, I think you have to redesign your test.

Comment: Thank you Erik. Very constructive answer. Do you think is it a good idea to create stubbed malformed api response? In that case AFNetworking should call `failure` block.